# XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer (typeof(MyClass) closes debugger session in visual studio but works in intermediate window

Tags: c#

I am facing a really strange issue:

`XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer (typeof(MyClass)` closes debugger session in visual studio but works in the immediate window

It was working before but suddenly started to behave like this.

Comment: What do you see in the Output window?

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in mysol.service.wcf.DLL
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><Exception><ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Is your application multi-threaded or uses PInvokes? 

I faced this problem sometimes when doing development a complex multi-threaded application with used WinPcap in VS2008 and 2010. Restarting the debugging session usually helped.

Comment: it's multi threaded. very complex solution. restarting debugging session didn't help.

Comment: ah... i got it. the error was because one of the property was Null and a method was throwing null exception. As its multi threaded app, the debugger was breaking at the line above. Thanks to Emiswelt and Hans Passant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi threaded application was breaking in another class with null exception.  stack trace in output window displays the error message.